# How to upsample/downsample by non-integer factors in R

Tags: r, time-series, signal-processing

I have a time series and I want to upsample and downsample it by some non-integer factor (e.g. 0.5 and 1.5). For the downsampling I have found the following simple solution.

```
time_series <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6)
sampling_index<-c(1,3,6)
sampled_time_series<-resample(time_series,seq(1,length(time_series)),sampling_index,interpol = 'spline')
```

But I do not know how to upsample, how can I go from 6 datapoints to 9 datapoints?

Comment: where are you getting `resample`? It's not a base R function. Either way, it sounds like you can use `approx` to up/down-sample fairly easily (though it's linear), and you could likely use the `spline` function in a similar way.

Comment: `resample` is from prospectr package. But you were right the `spline` function seems to do the trick. Thanks!